# Перевести из миллисекунд в HH:mm?

Tags: javascript, дата

пытаюсь вычислить разницу в миллисекундах

```
let res = addDays(parse(isodate), 2).getTime() - Date.now()
```

как мне перевести потом эту разницу в HH:mm ?

когда использую format из date fns получаю не то время

```
format(res, 'HH:mm');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала нужно получить общее число минут. Для этого исходное значение нужно поделить на 60000 (количество миллисекунд в одной минуте).

Потом это число нужно поделить на 60 (количество минут в часе) и отбросить дробную часть.

А для нахождения итогового числа минут, нужно найти остаток от деления общего числа минут на 60

```js
function msecToString(val) {
  var mins = Math.round(val / 60000);
  const hours = Math.floor(mins / 60);
  mins %= 60;
  if (mins < 10)
    mins = '0' + mins;
  return hours + ':' + mins;
}

console.log(msecToString(60000));
console.log(msecToString(3600000));
console.log(msecToString(3700000));
```

---

Чтобы получить форматирование через библиотеку, создайте объект `Date` и передайте его в функцию `format`

```
let res = addDays(parse(isodate), 2).getTime() - Date.now();
let dt = new Date(res);
console.log(format(res, 'HH:mm'));
```

Comment: а через библиотеку как можно?

Comment: Какую библиотеку?

Comment: date-fns
пробовал их format забзать
https://date-fns.org/v1.28.0/docs/format

Comment: Обновил ответ..

Comment: я так и сделал,но время получаю не то